# How to connect to database through SSH using DataGrip

Tags: sql, postgresql, ssh, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

To connect and set up properly with a command line, I "simply" have to do:

1. `ssh <MY_USERNAME>@<URL> -L 1139:arcade:139`
2. Enter `<MY_PASSWORD>`
3. `psql -h postgres`
4. `\c ift2935`
5. `set search_path to inscriptions_devoir;`

However, I've been tempted to use a more complex tool than the command line to explore the database and try out different SQL commands. Being a fan of `JetBrains`, I've decided to try out `DataGrip`.

I have indeed read [the actual help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#connect-to-postgresql-database) but it doesn't provide me with the information I need.

I lack the understanding of the jargon to know the correspondance, in terms, between the different lines I had to enter and the actual field-names that I am supposed to enter in `DataGrip`.

[image: DataGrip connection]

My question is quite simple: **what and where do I type the stuff ?**

Comment: Seems like there is an issue in DataGrip tracker. The second port is chosen randomly now: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6668

Comment: What second port?

Comment: I meant forward port.

Comment: After having everything configured correctly I was still getting an incorrect password message. Later, I realized that I need to set the database user password.

```alter user postgres password 'postgres'```

Things magically worked after that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out!

The SSH stuff was properly set up. The `Name` field at the very top was wrong.

For a `MySQL` database called `<DB_NAME>`, this would be the input (first image is for the `SSH` infos, the second one is for the `General` infos):

[image: SSH inputs]

[image: General inputs]

(Disregard the fact that the initial question was about `PostGreSQL`. The general idea stays the same.)

Comment: doesn't seeem like the solution, you screenshot had different hosts, idk why the name would matter.

Comment: @exts It's the same host listed in the "SSH/SSL" tab. You're looking at the "General" tab.

Answer (score 21):

I faced this issue too. So want to explain others how i managed to do it. lets say for example your remote server ip address is 192.128.11.120. Most of the time while tunneling the localhost/127.0.0.1 is used as the host ip address as in such scenarios the localhost ip is set as the bind address in the mysql config.

Here is the step by step guide on setup to connect to MySQL using SSH tunnel.

1 - Go to SSH/SSL tab and select 'Use SSH tunnel'

[image]

2 - Click  and do shift+enter or click three dots [...] to open SSH Configurations. From there click + sign to add a new configurations. Fill the form with your remote server ssh configurations.

- If you are using just one ssh key pair select 'OpenSSH config and authentication agent' as Authentication type.ssh key pair select following
- If you are using more than one key pair or want to use specific file select 'Key pair (OpenSSH or Putty)' as the Authentication type and select the private key file you used to connect to the remote server as the Private key file.

After that click 'Test Connection' to test whether SSH configuration is correct. If it works Click 'Apply' and 'OK' to save it.

[image]

Now  SSH is configured for DataGrip.

[image]

3 - Go to 'General' Tab to add the MySQL related entries. One thing to keep in mind is that most of the time the bind address is set to localhost/127.0.0.1 in MySql to make it secure on the remote servers to enable only ssh connections. In such cases the remote ip(in this case 192.128.11.120)  wont work. So, use 127.0.0.1. Click test connection to check whether the MySQL connection works over SSH.

[image]

4 - If it works, Click 'Apply' and 'OK' to save it.

Comment: Thanks for that simple solution

Comment: How can I add the unix socket connection to SSH Tunnel ?

Comment: My problem with the setup is that or mysql users are set to localhost. And even if I try the above with localhost as host, it seems to take 127.0.0.1 on the server side. Which MySQL treats differently than localhost (apparently localhost uses a socket conn. and 127.0.0.1 a tcp/ip conn.). 

Any solution to this, except changing users on mysql side?