# How Connect Unix Socket via SSH Tunnel in Datagrip

Tags: datagrip

How can I connect to a MySQL server via SSH Tunnel and get from the server the UNIX socket in Datagrip?

I found this partial solution, that helps me to configure SSH Tunnel but not get the socket file from the server.
[How to connect to database through SSH using DataGrip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54778659/4917663)

[image]

[image]

The server is MariaDB and I tried to use this information too but doesn't work

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010247880-How-to-connect-to-mariadb-via-unix-socket-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unix socket is not forwarded via SSH tunnel unless you perform some additional steps. the best approach is to use socat. something like that before connection:

```
/usr/bin/socat "UNIX-LISTEN:$SOCKET_DIR/mariadb-remote1.sock,reuseaddr,fork" \
EXEC:'/usr/bin/ssh -F /etc/sshssh_config -l root <remote1 host> -p 22 /usr/bin/socat STDIO UNIX-CONNECT\:/run/mariadb/mariadb.sock'
```

[Here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13645) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13646) you can find more useful information.

Comment: You are my savior, thank you very much! That works! I used the simple way of socat in my server. `socat -v tcp-l:3308,bind=localhost,reuseaddr,fork unix:/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`